# How to calculate formula from string to int

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I have a table that contains formula. Example of the formula:

**(GP1/(GP1 + GP2))*100%.**

In my code using **jquery**, i will replace GP1 with textbox1 value, GP2 with textbox2 value and remove the %.

I try to get the result by doing this:

```
var repl1 = (GP1/(GP1 + GP2))*100%;
var repl2 = repl1.replace(/GP1/gi,parseInt($("#txtbox1").val()));
var repl3 = repl2.replace(/GP2/gi,parseInt($("#txtbox2").val()));
var repl4 = repl3.replace(/%/gi,"");
```

==> so the last result will be:

```
 var repl4 = (10/(10+0))*100
```

I try to convert it to be int by doing this:

```
var result = parseInt(repl4);
```

But i get the result **NaN**.

Can anybody help me on how to calculate the formula

Thank you.

Comment: first print repl4 to check what it returns.Is there any string or special char occurs or not.

Comment: the result of the repl4 is : (10/(10+0))*100. I want the final result to be 1. Is there anyway to calculate this?

Comment: I guess in you example code above the first line is supposed to be a string but it is missing quotes.

Comment: It sounds like you are implementing a dynamic calculation engine. I had cause to implement a Dijkstra Shunting Yard parser for arbitrary (user entered!) formulae in JS a few years ago, for a similar sort of requirement.  Use a whitelist to restrict the functions allowed, and don't use eval...

Comment: Actually, I think it's okay to use eval depending on the usage of this application. Just remember that someone can always type `alert("Hacked!")` (and worse) into the text box. If there is some sort of save mechanism and other people can view what other users put in a textbox (random javascript will be run on other people's machine) I would not recommend `eval`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are looking for is:

```
var result = eval(repl4)
```

Be careful however as any Javascript in repl4 will be evaluated and executed, i.e. if someone types malicious Javascript into your text field it will get executed unless you filter it.

Applying `parseInt()` to the values of the text input however make the use of `eval()` acceptable in your example as it will return an integer or `NaN` thus preventing any code injection (this assumes of course that the formula is not coming from an `input` as well).

Comment: Never, *never*, `eval()` text fields, for exactly the reason stated here.

Comment: @LThode if you validate the input before passing it to `eval`, nothing bad will happen. For instance wrap it in a simple sanity check like `if(/^[-+*\/\d\s.()]+$/.test(repl4))` and the worst thing that can happen is an exception.

Comment: From my perspective the `parseInt()` should do the trick. It depends a bit on where the formula comes from then, but the inputs are covered.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("#btnCal").click(function(){
var repl1 = "(GP1/(GP1 + GP2))*100%";
var repl2 = repl1.replace(/GP1/gi,parseInt($("#txt1").val()));
var repl3 = repl2.replace(/GP2/gi,parseInt($("#txt2").val()));
var repl4 = repl3.replace(/%/gi,"");
  alert(eval(repl4));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txt1">
<input type="text" id="txt2">



<input type="button" id="btnCal" value="calculate">
```

Answer (score 2):

make use of eval after replacing values

```
var result = eval(repl4);
```

and put your expression in quotes otherwise it will show error like GP variable not declared or found

```
var repl1 = "(GP1/(GP1 + GP2))*100%";
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/254fqevd/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to use a dedicated parser to parse and later evaluate the expression. Relying on *eval* is a very easy attack vector for XSS attacks.

There are several maths library out there, the following example makes use of [math.js](http://mathjs.org/). Depending on your actual use case, it may be an overkill and a simple one-function hand-made parser suffices.

**Note** that I still had to include a little hack as math.js cannot cope with percent signs. Of course, a better way would be to actually include that functionality in math.js.

```js
var calculate = document.getElementById("calculate"),
  formula = document.getElementById("formula"),
  gp1 = document.getElementById("gp1"),
  gp2 = document.getElementById("gp2"),
  result = document.getElementById("result");


calculate.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var expr = formula.value.replace(/%/, "*(1/100)");
  result.value = math.eval(expr, {
    GP1: parseInt(gp1.value, 10),
    GP2: parseInt(gp2.value, 10)
  });
});
```

```html
GP1:
<input type="number" id="gp1" value="123" />
<br>GP2:
<input type="number" id="gp2" value="456" />Formula:
<input type="text" id="formula" value="(GP1/(GP1 + GP2))*100%" />
<hr>
<button id="calculate">Calculate!</button>
<br>Result:
<output>
  <input type="number" readonly="readonly" id="result" />
</output>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/1.5.0/math.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Good recommendation to use a purpose built library!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `var result = eval(repl4)`. This will evaluate the formular and store it into `result`.

Answer (score 1):

Running `parseInt((10/(10+0))*100);` will give you the answer you want, because it is a number, however `parseInt` can't convert the string '(10/(10+0))*100' into a number (most likely because of the non numeric characters.

you can (if you need to) get around it using `eval`, i.e.

`parseInt(eval('(10/(10+0))*100'));`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Webby2014/62vu0v0p/), I have also added the [missing radix parameter](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) within your `parseInt` method for completeness.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {

var repl1 = '(GP1/(GP1 + GP2)) * 100%';

var repl2 = repl1.replace(/GP1/gi, parseInt($('#txtbox1').val(), 10));
var repl3 = repl2.replace(/GP2/gi, parseInt($('#txtbox2').val(), 10));
var repl4 = repl3.replace(/%/gi, "");

$('#result').html(repl4);

});
```